# How to horizontally stack elements using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a custom audio player, with basically:

- a button for playing
- a *flexible* bar, i.e., that adapts itself to the player width
- a group of button at the right of the player, namely for the download button etc

For the two first parts I have no problem (see the fiddle), but it's for the second button group I have troubles.

I tried to put the group with `float:right`, but in this case it is kicked out from the player. Then I tried to put the `flexible` bar with a floating property, but in this case I have to specify its width and it becomes no more flexible.

Here is a sample image of what I want to achieve:
[image]

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="player" style="width:500px">
  <div class="group">
    <a class="button" href="#"></a> 
  </div>
  <div class="flexible">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.player 
{
    height:24px;
    background-color: #222222;
}

.player .group 
{    
    float:left;
}

.player .group .button,
.player .group2 .button
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    background-color:#444444;
}

.player .group2 
{
    float:right;
}

.player .flexible
{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.player .flexible .bar 
{
    margin : 8px;
    height : 8px;
    background-color:#225599;     
}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/grh7sahq/3/

Do you have any advice ?

Thanks

Comment: It would be great if you have an image showing what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood you wanted the central part to be flexible. You can use display: flex. Really basic CSS to show it:

```css
.player{
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.button{
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 24px;
  display: block;
}

.flexible{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="player" style="width:500px">
  <div class="group">
    <a class="button" href="#"></a> 
  </div>
  <div class="flexible">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group2">
    <a class="button" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>

<div class="player" style="width:150px">
  <div class="group">
    <a class="button" href="#"></a> 
  </div>
  <div class="flexible">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group2">
    <a class="button" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aaaaw yeah, that's great thanks ! This really makes life easier: https://jsfiddle.net/grh7sahq/4/

Answer (score 0):

change this css class to use `inline` style...

```
.player .group .button,
.player .group2 .button
{
    display: inline;
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    background-color:#444444;
}
```

Comment: Actually when doing that, the `width` and `height` properties have no effect, and the buttons disappear: https://jsfiddle.net/v6d918aL/

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gadumiloza/4/edit?html,css,js,output)
It is actually pretty simple with flex box

[image]

```
<div class="player">
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="seek">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.player{
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #555;
  display: flex;
}

.player>.button{
   width: 35px;
}

.player>.seek{
   padding: 10px;
   flex-grow: 1;
}

.player>.seek>div{
  background-color: #0af;
  height: 100%;
}
```